# How to make sure user enters all details before loading next screen

Tags: java, android, exception, android-edittext

I want the user to enter all text in edittext before it loads the next screen. If the user presses done and they have not filled in all details, it should display a message telling them to do so.

```
try {
                if (Integer.toString(cigSmoked).length() > 0) {
                    cigSmoked = Integer.parseInt(cigSmokedText.getText()
                            .toString());
                    editor.putInt("smokedCigaretes", cigSmoked);
                    editor.commit();
                }
                if (Integer.toString(cigBox).length() > 0) {
                    cigBox = Integer.parseInt(cigBoxText.getText()
                            .toString());
                    editor.putInt("cigaretteBox", cigBox);
                    editor.commit();
                }
                if (Float.toString(cigCost).length() > 0) {
                    cigCost = Float.parseFloat(cigCostText.getText()
                            .toString());
                    editor.putFloat("cigaretteCost", cigCost);
                    editor.commit();
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Did NOT save settings, please fill in all fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                ;
            }

            int day = quitYearText.getDayOfMonth();
            int month = quitYearText.getMonth();
            int year = quitYearText.getYear();
            editor.putInt("day", day);
            editor.putInt("month", month);
            editor.putInt("year", year);
            editor.commit();

            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            CharSequence text = "Saved!";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
            toast.show();

            Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.this, Home.class);
            Settings.this.startActivity(myIntent);

        }
```

Comment: So...what ? What's your problem/error ? :)

Answer (score 1):

You just get value from edittext and check the length of string that you got from editext. like below.

```
String str=editext.getText().tostring.trim(); 
String str2=editext2.getText().tostring.trim(); 
..
..
if(str.length()>0 || str2.length()>0 ......){
   //your navigation code
}else{
  //your alert message
}
```

do this for every editext. hope this may help you.

Comment: I have tried this but the application crashes when fields left blank

Comment: here you are also check for null value or blank value or you just add trim() method for all edittext like below: String str=editetxt.getText().trim().toString;

Comment: It now stays on the screen, however when i enter all the details it still stays on the same screen and shows message ' enter all details'

Answer (score 0):

You can do like follow, no need to write so many condition

```
String str=editText1.getText.toString();
String str1=editText2.getText.toString();
.
.
.
.
String strn=editTextn.getText.toString();
```

now check condition

```
if(str.length()>0 || str1.length>0 || strn.length>0){
               // whatever code you want to put
}else{
   //alert dialog saying field is empty
}
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Write one function.

```
 private String validateForm()
{
    try
    {
        if(mEditTextFirstName.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
        {
            return "Oops..plz Enter First Name";
        }
        if(mEditTextLastName.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
        {
            return "Oops..plz Enter Last Name";
        }
        if(mEditTextEmail.getText().toString().trim().equals(""))
        {
            return "Oops..plz Enter Email";
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(Error e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "";
}
```

then,

```
String errorMessage = validateForm();
            if(errorMessage.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
            {
                             // Do whatever You want.
            }               
            else
            {
                       Toast.makeText(getActivity(), errorMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```